# How to define nested columns in JavaFX within the fxml file?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I would like produce the following table using fxml:
[image]

So, I wonder how can I nest the columns Primary and Secondary inside Email Address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking some code in this [link](http://fievus.blogspot.com/2013/06/javafx-tableview-nested-tablecolumn.html), I was able to figure it out.

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" text="First Name" prefWidth="100"/>
        <TableColumn text="Last Name" prefWidth="100"/>
        <TableColumn text="Email Address" prefWidth="300">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text ="Primary" prefWidth="150"/>
                <TableColumn text ="Secondary" prefWidth="150"/>
            </columns>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```